# How to write a redirect with regular expression

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect all incoming links  with htaccess from

```
/2011/05/16/xps-15z-dell-laesst-sich-vom-apple-macbook-inspirieren/
```

to

```
/xps-15z-dell-laesst-sich-vom-apple-macbook-inspirieren/
```

how would look the regex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the work

```
RewriteRule ^/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/(.*)/?$ /$1
```

Or even this

```
RewriteRule ^/\d+/\d+/\d+/(.*)/?$ /$1
```

Comment: You could add a `[R]` at the end if you want an external redirect.